# Wifi is not working in hcl me laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, hotkeys

I'm using a HCL ME notebook l 1044. previously i had Windows 8 32 bit installed, and the hotkeys for activating and deactivating wifi are working properly  <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

until I upgraded to Windows 8.1 64 bit. Now the hotkey does not work, even after I've installed the 64 bit hot key program.

i am using dual operating system while turning on wifi from another os i can use wifi in  windows 8.1.
it mean the wifi driver is working fine , but i am not able to turn on or off the wifi via hotkey (Keyboard).

How would I solved it please help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What specific model?

Comment: Hcl me notebook l 1044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the [wifi driver](http://www.hclsupportservice.in/drvr-dwnld.jsp?pF=Tm90ZWJvb2s=) in your HCL ME Notebook in order to your wireless connection to work.

Comment: I already installed,  actually i am using dual os after turning on wifi from other os it will work on windows 8.1. But from windows 8.1 it's not working...

Comment: i didn't get you (are you using virtual box ?)

Comment: No i am not using virtual box, i have installed Windows 7 in one drive and windows 8.1 in another, previously it was working in windows 8 32 bit but after installing windows 8.1 64 bit it's not working

Comment: ok..is it working fine with windows 7?

Comment: yeah , it's working fine in windows 7, even previously its working fine with windows 8 32 bit also

Comment: (using windows 8.1) go to device manager and uninstall your wifi driver and restart ur system. and also tell me your laptop model

Comment: my laptop model is hcl me notebook l 1044. i already done , but it's not working . even i tried to update the driver manually also.

Comment: check the link and install this one if you have not.. http://www.solvusoft.com/en/update/drivers/laptop/hcl/me-laptop/1044/model-numbers/